# How to get id number from different locale in model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, locale

I have one model (category.rb) in my rails application configured as below:

> id,name,locale
>
> 1,Sociability,en
>
> 2,Prudence and Delicacy,en
>
> 3,社會性,zh-TW
>
> 4,"謹慎性，細膩性",zh-TW

I would like to know the initial ID for different locale, for example, the initial ID for :en will be "1" and ID for :"zh-TW" will be "3".  Instead of hard-coded to define the initial ID in application, is there any gem or method to identify the initial ID?  So that in future, when I add new record as 5, Sociabilidad, es, I can get the ID correctly without hard-coded?

Please advise.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you using postgresql?

Comment: Thanks for promptly response.  No, I use "MySQL".  Will it make difference for postgresql?

Comment: No some DB specific functions sometime, so it is better to know before I suggest something. tag the question with mysql also

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!

Comment: @strawberry it was a dup in SQL, but not Rails. So I reopened it and shown the OP how to write it in Rails AR way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write this as below using AR:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  scope :first_in_locale, ->() {
    joins(<<-SQL)
      JOIN (SELECT locale, min(id) AS id FROM categories GROUP BY locale) b ON b.id = categories.id
    SQL
    .select('categories.*')
    .order('categories.id')
  }
end
```

In Rails console:

```
2.5.1 :010 > pp Category.first_in_locale
  Category Load (0.9ms)  SELECT categories.* FROM "categories" JOIN (SELECT locale, min(id) as id from categories group by locale) b on b.id = categories.id ORDER BY categories.id
[#<Category:0x00007fc597e3db68
  id: 1,
  name: "Sociability",
  locale: "en",
  created_at: Sun, 16 Sep 2018 07:47:34 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 16 Sep 2018 07:47:34 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Category:0x00007fc597e3d3e8
  id: 3,
  name: "社會性",
  locale: "zh-TW",
  created_at: Sun, 16 Sep 2018 07:47:34 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 16 Sep 2018 07:47:34 UTC +00:00>]
```

Here is the [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22942571/2767755) answer I wrapped in ActiveRecord way.

Comment: Sorry for delay.  Thanks for the solution, which completely meet my expectation.

Comment: @JoeyChou Happy to help you.. :)